# Sound stopped and I must reboot to make it work again

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio

When I bood the computer the sound works well, but after I suspend one or two times, then sound stop working.

```
pulseaudio -vvvvv

I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) falló: Operación no permitida 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) falló: Operación no permitida 
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us. 
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked. 
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Esto es PulseAudio 4.0 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Host de compilación: i686-pc-linux-gnu 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilación CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
-Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ejecutándose en el host: Linux i686 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:16:27 UTC 2013 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Se encontraron 2 CPUs. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: El tamaño de la página es de 4096 bytes 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Soporte para compilar con Valgrind: no 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ejecutándose en modo valgrind: no 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ejecutando en MV: no 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Build optimizado: si 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH definido, solo se desactivan las comprobaciones fast path. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: El ID de la máquina es 0b8080c47e0b8c2a7648aa695179af88 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: El ID de la sesión es c2. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Utilizando directorio de tiempo de ejecución /run/user/1000/pulse. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Utilizando directorio de estado /home/jose/.config/pulse. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Utilizando directorio de módulos /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules. 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ejecutándose en modo de sistema: no 
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running. 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: failed pa_pid_file_create().
```

I used pavucontrol and when I play a video or a song, I can see se sound bar moving but I can not hear anyting.

Comment: Could add the question the results of these commands for both cases *BEFORE* and *AFTER* sound stops `pactl stat` , `pactl list short` , `sudo lsmod` , use http://paste.ubuntu.com/. In addition to `sudo lshw -C multimedia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem resolved by following most of these steps. 
I hope this help as much as it help me.
[Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)